# Optimisation of For looping with zip() for handling huge data computations

Tags: python

I am writing a code in python for my research code which is used to handle huge data. I use 3D arrays along with 1D arrays. I use for loops frequently in my code. I would like to optimise the for loops with better options such as zip() and if possible any other better coding idea. I wrote a sample code here, with all features I use in my coding. For example: Call a function with in a loop, 2. multiplication of each element of a 2D code with each element of a 1D array as shown in the code. Kindly guide me.

```
#*******************************************************************
import numpy as np
import time
import random
#*******************************************************************
Nx = 5    # resolution x-dir
Ny = 5    # resolution y-dir
NL = 7
weights = np.array([0.2,0.5,0.8,1.5,2.8,5.9,1.5]) # sums to 1
ux = np.array([[1, 2,3,4,5], [3, 4,6,8,9], [1, 4,3,6,2], [4, 5,7,4,3], [1, 2,6,5,11]])
print(ux)
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
def add(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return(c)
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Normal For Looping
def main():
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(Nx):
        for j in range(Ny):
            sum = 0.0
            for k in range(NL):
                a= add(i,j)
                sum= sum + weights[k]*ux[i,j]+a
            ux[i,j]= sum
    end = time.time()
    print('Time:',end-start)
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    print(ux)
#
    return 0
#++++++++++++++++++++++
if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Define “huge”. Have you tried using numpy methods directly?

Comment: Looping through the arrays is going to be slower than using faster vectorized functions implemented via numpy

Comment: "I use for loops frequently in my code..." If you are using manual loops with numpy arrays, you are missing a lot of the power of numpy. I recommend that you read about vectorizing with numpy. This can most likely help you remove explicit loops from your code.

Comment: What we mean by vectorization is that for example the innermost loop can be replaced with `sum = weights.sum() * ux[i,j] + NL * add(i, j)`. I would offer to vectorize the entire program to teach by example but the silliness of the add function in particular makes me think this code is somewhat detached from your real code

Comment: "`np.array([0.2,0.5,0.8,1.5,2.8,5.9,1.5]) # sums to 1`" - No it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thing that stands out, your inner loop over `k` contains two invariants: `ux[i,j]` and `a`. These could be pushed out of the inner loop, reducing the amount of additions and lookups:

```py
def main():
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(Nx):
        for j in range(Ny):
            tot = 0.0
            val = ux[i, j] + i + j

            for k in range(NL):
                tot += weights[k] * val

            ux[i,j]= tot

    end = time.time()
    print('Time:',end-start)
```

Now that this has happened, we can see that we really can just do `weights * val` and eliminate the inner loops entirely:

```py
def main():
    for i in range(Nx):
        for j in range(Ny):
            val = ux[i, j] + i + j

            ux[i,j]= (weights * val).sum()
```

But since the multiplication of `weights` and `val` being added is commutative, `weights.sum()` is a constant, and can just be:

```py
weight = weights.sum()

def main():
    for i in range(Nx):
        for j in range(Ny):
            val = ux[i, j] + i + j
            ux[i,j] = val * weight
```

This should cut your computation time by a decent amount already.

The last bit uses `np.grid` to get the indexes of each position in `ux`:

```py
grid = np.indices((5, 5))

# grid[0] is row indices and grid[1] is column indices
arr = grid[0] + grid[1] + ux

# and finally, the multiplication of each value against
# the weight constant
result = arr * weight
```

So your whole code boils down to:

```py
def main():
    grid = np.indices((Nx, Ny))
    weight = weights.sum()

    arr = ux + grid[0] + grid[1]

    result = arr * weight
```

Comment: Thank you all for your observations. I will train myself on numpy and optimise my code to improve speed. Thank you